# Is there some kind of bug preventing me from receiving the "Curious" badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

According to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/57983/blaze) I have 17/5 for the Curious badge. So I have effectively 'earned' this badge more than 3 times over. So why haven't I received it yet? I have maintained a positive question record so what do I have to do to get this elusive badge?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/what-is-the-positive-question-record

Comment: Yes, exact duplicate, but that user only asked 6 questions, I have asked 17 well-received questions and _still_ don't have the badge. If my rep was high enough I could use that formula in @David Z 's answer and find out why myself. But my rep is too low to see deleted posts.

Comment: No, you haven't "earned" this badge either once, twice, or thrice over; the requirements are very clear and the answer has not changed since David's answer was posted. The metric for 'positive question record' (which your profile badge tracker will tell you you don't meet at the moment) is public and detailed in David's post. It's impossible for non-mods to help because your deleted posts are not visible, but in essence, if you have four questions which are closed and deleted and have negative score, that would kill your positive question record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on the bronze bar, it shows that having a positive question record is the requirement you need to fulfull.

[image: screenshot of popup on profile]

A full description of the requirements for the badge is available [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399). It includes the requirement for a positive question record:

> - A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

Looking over your profile, I see that you have enough negative-score, closed, and/or deleted questions to make this statistic less than 0.5.